# Remove namespace from XAttribute

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, linq-to-xml, xattribute

It would be really nice to be able to remove the namespace (`xmlns:icls="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0"`) from the `classificationType` attribute.

Code so far:

```
public XElement BuildXml() {
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0";
    var root = new XElement(ns + "InvoicesDoc", new XAttribute("xmlns", ns));
    var x = new XElement(ns + "incomeClassification",
                new XElement(ns + "classificationType",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "icls", ns), "somevalue"));
    root.Add(x);
    return root;
}
```

Output based on the above code:

```
<InvoicesDoc xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0">
    <incomeClassification>
        <icls:classificationType xmlns:icls="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0">somevalue</icls:classificationType>
    </incomeClassification>
</InvoicesDoc>
```

Desired output should not have the namespace in the attribute:

```
<InvoicesDoc xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0">
    <incomeClassification>
        <icls:classificationType>somevalue</icls:classificationType>
    </incomeClassification>
</InvoicesDoc>
```

Comment: Your desired XML is malformed, according to [Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition): Qualified Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-qualnames): *The Prefix provides the namespace prefix part of the qualified name, and MUST be associated with a namespace URI reference in a namespace declaration.*  Note the emphasis on MUST.  For confirmation you can upload your desired XML to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will get an error.   I don't believe that LINQ to XML supports creating malformed XML like that.

Comment: What I think you can do is to write the XML manually using the old .NET 1 [`XmlTextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter) and set [`XmlTextWriter.Namespaces = false`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.namespaces?view=net-8.0).  But this is really old functionality that (as far as I know, could be wrong) didn't get implemented in LINQ to XML.

Comment: Incidentally, is the `XElement` returned by your `BuildXml()` going to be a root element of some document?  Or is going to be nested inside some root element within which `icls:` is going to be defined?

Comment: @dbc Thanks for replying.  The structure of the XML is given by the IAPR https://www.aade.gr/en. Here's the complete structure https://www.aade.gr/sites/default/files/2020-09/SampleXML_2.1_taxes_per_invoice%20%28%CE%A4.%CE%A0.%CE%A5%29.xml

Answer (score 0):

As @dbc suggested, I tried xmlTextWriter and worked fine. I built the xml line-by-line.

```
using XmlTextWriter writer = new("fileName.xml", null);
writer.Namespaces = false;
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
writer.WriteStartElement("InvoicesDoc");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:icls", "https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:ecls", "https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi:schemaLocation", "http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0/InvoicesDoc-v0.6.xsd");
    writer.WriteStartElement("invoice");
        writer.WriteStartElement("invoiceSummary");
            writer.WriteElementString("totalNetValue", 1);
            writer.WriteElementString("totalVatAmount", 0.24);
            writer.WriteElementString("totalWithheldAmount", 0);
            writer.WriteElementString("totalFeesAmount", 0);
            writer.WriteElementString("totalStampDutyAmount", 0);
            writer.WriteElementString("totalOtherTaxesAmount", 0);
            writer.WriteElementString("totalDeductionsAmount", 0);
            writer.WriteElementString("totalGrossValue", 1.24);
            writer.WriteStartElement("incomeClassification");
                writer.WriteElementString("icls:classificationType", "Description A");
                writer.WriteElementString("icls:classificationCategory", "Description B");
                writer.WriteElementString("icls:amount", "Description C");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.Close();
```